# How to receive syslog messages and convert them to string

Tags: java, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng, syslog4j

First I would like to receive the syslog message, the second I would like to syslog message into string type, please tell me how to write java code。

The following code can only be output in the console, how to get the string type of message.

```
SyslogServerEventHandlerIF eventHandler = new PrintStreamSyslogServerEventHandler(System.out);
SyslogServerIF serverIF = SyslogServer.getInstance("udp");
SyslogServerConfigIF config = serverIF.getConfig();
config.setHost("192.168.1.114");
config.setPort(10000);
config.addEventHandler(eventHandler);
serverIF.initialize("udp",config);
serverIF.run();
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: @rkosegi  The above code can only be output in the console, how to get the string type of message

Comment: this code seems to spawn syslog server. You want to receive message. confused.

Comment: @rkosegi  This code is to receive the message and then print to the console, introducing the syslog.jar package.

Comment: @rkosegi Because I want to parse the syslog message, so I want to get a String type of message first, and then use regular expressions to match

Comment: @rkosegi  I want to parse syslog messages coming to a syslog server implemented in syslog4J.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache-camel for receiving messages over UDP and then unmarshal using syslog dataformat. It supports both RFC3164 and RFC5424.
REFER : http://camel.apache.org/syslog.html